# Use perfect scrollbar with Angular virtual scroll

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using the `ngx-perfect-scrollbar` package in application everywhere where scrolling is used. Recently, I switched to the Angular virtual scroll for optimization reasons, but the default scrollbar is very distracting. Is there a way to use the perfect scrollbar instead of the default one?

Previous code:

```
<perfect-scrollbar *ngIf="!loading" #scrollbar [config]="horizontalScrollConfig">
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <component *ngFor="let item of items"></component>
  </div>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

Updated code:

```
<div class="cdk-virtual-scroll-data-source">
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="53" orientation="horizontal" class="viewport hidden-scrollbar">
    <component *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items"></component>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</div>
```

I have tried applying the `[perfectScrollbar]` directive to the `div` wrapper, I have also tried wrapping the `div` inside the `perfect-scrollbar`, but nothing helped.

Is it possible to use the `perfect-scrollbar` with virtual scrolling?